# Intel GMA 4500 driver for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers

I have a Thinkpad X200 with Intel GMA 4500MHD onboard graphics. As of 2018, it seems that Intel is no longer supporting this card and there is no official driver available for Windows 10 on the Intel website. The generic driver provided by Windows does not support hardware 3D acceleration despite the card having OpenGL 2.1 capabilities.

Does anybody know where Windows 10 compatible drivers for this card can be found? Given that neither Intel nor Microsoft have released one, is there a third party driver available anywhere, or one hacked together by enthusiasts?

Failing that, what would it take to modify the Windows 7 driver so that it works in Windows 10?

Comment: In the past, I have installed Windows 7/8 drivers on Windows 10, of course, not all might be compatible with Windows 10. (Don’t @ me on this).

Comment: I've also installed Vista/7 drivers on Windows 7/8 before. Most will work fine because the kernels are all 6.x and the device driver structure is the same. Just remember to run the installer in compatibility mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 2019, an improved custom driver is available from nIGHTmAYOR. It is working a treat on my Thinkpad X200S.

Here is a copy of the driver on Google Drive:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y7S3HEcgFHvqwFOnQS2jDV6Mejxu4iZP/view?usp=sharing

And here is the original post on the Windows 10 forums with 4shared link:

https://www.tenforums.com/graphic-cards/130380-custom-driver-intel-gma-4500-mhd-extreme-plus-nighmayor.html

Kudos to nIGHTmAYOR for putting so much effort into this!

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of digging around the internet I managed to find a custom driver that worked for me:

http://worldintelmoddriver.blogspot.com/p/intel-x4500.html

To install I had to first disable Microsoft signature checking:

1. Run command prompt as administrator and type the following 2 commands:

   ```
   bcdedit -set loadoptions DISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
   bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING ON
   ```
2. Restart computer
3. Download the driver from the link above & install it
4. Re-enable signature checking:

   ```
   bcdedit -set loadoptions ENABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
   bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING OFF
   ```

It worked, now it's 2018 and I have OpenGL 2.1, hooray...