# uninstall Intel GMA 4500 driver for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, display-driver

I tried to install this drivers but on step 2 error message popped up saying, my computer is does not have supporting hardware or something like that.  Is it possible to uninstall the step 1 now?  I see my pc desktop [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32yat.jpg)displays test mode message.  Thank you.

Comment: Intel GMA4500 Driver uninstall

Comment: It did not install anything, nothing to do.

Comment: There is no official Win10 driver for Intel GMA - see https://superuser.com/questions/1376426/intel-gma-4500-driver-for-windows-10